# windows c : failed to create mmap of a file

Tags: c, windows, mmap, createfile

**I need to create mmap of a file. Since windows does not support mmap, i tried MapViewOfFile() method. But this fails.**

**Here's my code :**

```
char template[1024];
snprintf(template, sizeof(template) / sizeof(char), "%s", "C:\\Users\\Ijas\\Downloads\\ijas.txt");

HANDLE  hfile = CreateFile(template, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, NULL);

if (hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "CreateFile() error 0x%08x \n", GetLastError());
    return NULL;
}

HANDLE map_handle = CreateFileMapping(hfile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_RESERVE, 0, 0, 0);
if (map_handle == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "CreateFileMapping() error 0x%08x\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hfile);
    return NULL;

}

sp = (char*)MapViewOfFile(map_handle, FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

if (sp->buffer == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "MapViewOfFile() error 0x%08x\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    CloseHandle(hfile);
    return NULL;
}
```

**Output :**

```
CreateFile() error 0x00000003
```

**Hint : template is an existing file.**

Anything wrong in my code? Please help me out?

Comment: Does `ijas.txt` exists? You should call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what went wrong with function call.

Comment: When a Windows system call fails, you should use [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) to find what [the error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have edited my code & output with GetLastError

Comment: @WhozCraig I have edited my code & output with last error

Comment: @IjasAhamed `0x3 == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`...

Comment: @LPs updated my output with last error code

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but file exists

Comment: **ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND** means _The system cannot find the path specified._

Comment: @LPs but file exits. Is any problem with permission?

Comment: go to command prompt and execute `dir c:\Users\Ijas\Downloads\ijas.txt`

Comment: The file exists but the path is not correct...

Comment: Ar all components (directories) in the path spelled correctly? You haven't formatted the filesystem to be case-sensitive? If you copy the string from your program into an explorer window, does it find the file?

Comment: Have you tried using `CreateFileA` instead of `CreateFile`?

Comment: I tried dir c:\Users\Ijas\Downloads\ijas.txt, file exists and it shows the file size.

Comment: How is `template` declared?

Comment: @LPs updated the code how template is assigned.

Comment: @Abhineet Tried CreateFileA, but creashes.

Comment: @LPs tried your sprintf, and tried to printf template, it shows like this C:\\Users\\Ijas\\Downloads\\ijas.txt

Comment: That should be exacly what CreateFile needs..

Comment: Change the variable name `template` to something else like `temp` or anything.

Comment: What is your filename? Are you compiling it as a cpp file or c file? `template` is a keyword in cpp. Also, if `CreateFileA` is crashing, there must be some hint in it.

Comment: @LPs tried your sprintf, but still same error persists.

Comment: @Abhineet I am compiling in c. Changed template to temp, but no change.

Comment: @LP - There is no need to escape double slashes in `snprintf`.

Comment: What IDE or compiler you are using?

Comment: I think, the problem is with the `snprintf` declaration. Are you getting any warning regarding undefinition of `snprintf`. Just to narrow down the problem, try `char* template = "C:\\Users\\Ijas\\Downloads\\ijas.txt";` and comment the whole code block of `char template[1024];` & `snprintf` code.

Comment: @Abhineet Problem was with CreateFile. Tried CreateFileA, works fine.

Comment: Good to know, but earlier you said that it crashes?

Comment: @Abhineet sorry, that crash was from some other part of my code. I thought it was with createfileA. Thanks a lot. Please post your answer below.

Comment: Then I will put the comment as answer.

Comment: @Abhineet just out of curiosity: what's the difference between Ansi version and std version of CreateFile?

Comment: I have put the details in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, with various possibilities of try-and-hit, the problem seems to be with `Unicode` and `Ansi`. `template` is declared as `char*` but is passed to `CreateFile` which by default calls `CreateFileW`. If OP would have compiled the code with C++ compiler, the compiler would have complained about this but with C compiler, it just relied on the coder's intellect.

`CreateFileA` expects `const char*` whereas `CreateFileW` expects `const wchar_t*`

Comment: @LPs - If I can, I would have shared points with you. You only ruled out more than half of the possibilities of error and narrowed down the problem.